# Gtk3 Transparent Container

Tags: css, c, transparent, gtk3, glade

I'm working on a Gtk3 application. Therefore I designed the window on Ubuntu with Glade 3.16.1.
I have a GtkWindow layout with a vertical seperating GtkPaned. Loading a CSS file I give the window a background image like this:

```
GtkWindow#window {
    background-image: url("Glade Prototype/background.png");
}
```

But It seems like the layout component is drawn on it with a solid color  and so the background image is only partially visible. You can see it
[here](http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150430/zvvxf6va.png)

My first try was setting the background color of the layout transparent, but it didn't changed anything (Any other color works):

```
GtkPaned#mainLayout {   
    background-color: transparent;
    /* OR: background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) */
    /* OR: background-image: none */
}
```

Thanks for help,

Greetings Thomas

PS: Does anyone have a Glade version for Windows supporting Gtk3 (+CSS)? I only found Glade 3.8 (CSS supporting versions are e.g. 3.16 / 3.18) on their website.

**Edit:** Here a better example for this problem:

```
GtkWindow#window {
    background-color: #00FF00;
}
GtkPaned#mainLayout {   
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)
}
```

-> [Image with Alpha 50% / 0.5](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3980/u9uagdfv_png.htm)

You can see that it looks like a mix of red and white color. But i want that white color to disappear.

**Edit2:**
I've also tried overriding the draw function and drawing a transparent rectangle with Cairo -> No success. My code:

```
G_MODULE_EXPORT gboolean drawMainContainer(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data) {
    guint width, height;
    GdkRGBA color;

    width = gtk_widget_get_allocated_width (widget);
    height = gtk_widget_get_allocated_height (widget);
    cairo_rectangle (cr, 0, 0, width, height);

    gtk_style_context_get_color (gtk_widget_get_style_context (widget),
            0,
            &color);
    cairo_set_source_rgba (cr, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    cairo_fill (cr);    
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Can you show `background.png` on its own (i.e. not loaded to the interface)?

Comment: My screenshot might be confusing because there is an preview image in my central layout ;) You can see the real background only at the side -> [background.png](http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150502/ykvvh3mc.png)

Comment: You might want to try `background-color: rgba (0, 0, 0, 0);` but I have no idea whether it will work. Perhaps you can paste a minimal compilable example that shows the problem (together with the glade file)? Then before making suggestions I can at least test it myself.

Comment: Nice try but didn't work :( I've updated my question with a simpler example